# Error in stored procedure on Phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have created this simple StoredProcedure in the Phpmyadmin SQL console but I keep getting syntax errors. I have looked at similar created StoredProcedures but can't seem to figure out what the error is. Here is my StoredProcedure:

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS addnewemployee //
CREATE PROCEDURE addnewemployee 
(
IN eno INT(11),
IN ebdate date,
IN efname VARCHAR(14),
IN elname VARCHAR(16),
IN egender enum,
IN ehdate date
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO employees(emp_no, birth_date, first_name, last_name, gender, hire_date) 
  values (eno, ebdate, efname, elname, egender, ehdate);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

And this is the error message seen in Phpmyadmin sql console:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ',
IN ehdate date
)
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO employees(eno, ebdate, efname, elname' at line 7
```

Comment: The error message does not match the posted code.

Comment: And where doesn't it match?

Comment: In your question, obviously. Also, your `enum` type definition seems incomplete.

Comment: Check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ac30b9b93f3798525a39a29a1838bb4f) out.

Comment: It is complete by my knowledge level that is the code I entered into the phpmyadmin console. But I changed it to `varchar` and the error went away but your link is the right way to do it. I am yound at this so that answer is what I needed. Thanks

Comment: `enum` datatype cannot be used as a parameter type. Use full spec of a type.

Comment: I just noticed that I am trying to use a string! Will that be ok!

Comment: You can use string type. You can use integer type (see for conversion). You can use fully specified (including all enumerated values) enum type. If using literals is not critical the integer type seems to be the best variant.

Comment: The mysql type is enum so I am trying to pass a value into the stored procedure!

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
IN egender enum,
```

to

```
IN egender VARCHAR(99),
```

That will let you pass a string into the prodecure, then when doing the `INSERT`, the string will be acceptable to the `ENUM` column.

An analogy -- You don't have to be precise about numeric (TINYINT/BIGINT/FLOAT/DECIMAL, or even a string) when you pass it into a procedure.  What matters is whether the context (`INSERT` in your case) can convert it as needed.

Note, as usual, that 1064 pointed 'exactly' at the bad spot -- either the comma or what was immediately before it.  In this case `enum` ease expecting `(...)`, so it was surprised by the comma.